# update multiple rows mysql using php and checkboxes

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

I am creating a system in which a user will be able to change the "status" of an item in a MySQL table.

Basically my table has a unique (auto incrementing) ID field, and 18 other fields. One of those fields is a status field. I need to figure out a way to change the status from "active" to "hold" when a user checks off a checkbox.

I am assuming that if I assign a value to the checkbox and feed it into an auto incrementing array, that it should pull through when it's checked. I don't know if this is correct though.

Every time I try it, the only status that gets changed is the 1st one and that's it. Here's my code that pulls out the entry's:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            echo "<table border='2' style='width: 100%; margin: auto; border-width: 1px'><tr><th>Date Requested</th><th>Time Called</th><th>Tenant Name</th><th>Apartment</th><th>Work Requested</th><th>Tenant need to be present?</th><th>Good Date</th><th>Time to complete</th><th>Resident Phone #</th></tr>";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='id[$i]' value=" . $row['id'] . ">";
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td align='center'>" . date("m-d-Y", strtotime($row['r_date'])) . "</td>";
            echo "<td align='center'>" . date("g:i A", strtotime($row['t_call'])) . "</td>";
            echo "<td align='center'>" . $row['t_name'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td align='center'>" . $row['loc'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td align='center'>" . $row['w_req'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td align='center'>" . $row['apt_status'] . "</td>";
            if ($row['to_be'] == "1969-12-31") {
                echo "<td align='center'> </td>";
                }
            else {
                echo "<td align='center'>" . date("m-d-Y", strtotime($row['to_be'])) . "</td>";
                };
            echo "<td align='center'>" . $row['g_time'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td align='center'>" . $row['tel'] . "</td></tr>";
            echo "<tr><td align='center' colspan = '3' style='border-width:0px; background-color: #E6E6E6'><strong>Work performed/notes:</strong><br><textarea name='work[$i]'style='width:250px; height:60px'>" . htmlspecialchars($row['w_performed'], ENT_QUOTES) . "</textarea></td>";
            echo "<td colspan='2' align='center' style='border-width:0px; background-color: #E6E6E6'><strong>Check to put Work Order on hold.</strong><br><input name='holding' type='checkbox' value='" . $row['id'] . "' ></td>";
            echo "<td colspan='4' style='border-width:0px; background-color: #E6E6E6'>&nbsp;</td>";
            echo "<tr><td colspan='9' style='border-width:0px'><hr style='height:3px; color: #333; background-color: #333'></td>";
            ++$i;
        }
echo "</table>";
```

And the code I've been trying to use to pull through the ID using the checkbox is this:

```
$i = 0;

        $size = count($_POST['holding']);
        while($i < $size) 
        {

        while(isset($_POST['holding'][$i]))
        {
            $sql = "UPDATE w_o SET w_status = 'hold' WHERE id = " . $_POST['id'][$i];
            mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql) or die('Error: ' . $mysqli_error($mysqli));
            ++$i;
        }
        }
```

I feel like I'm WAY off and would appreciate any help. I've googled how to do this a gazillion times and for some reason I can't seem to find a good enough tutorial. Thank you for your help!

Comment: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). `$_POST` data **NEVER** goes directly into a query.

Answer (score 1):

All of your checkboxes will have the same `holding` name. Upon submission, PHP will only use ONE of the multiple values submitted. If you want to submit multiple different values, you either have to give each field a unique name, or use PHP's "array" hack for the field name: `holding[]`. Adding the `[]` tells PHP to expect multiple values, and `$_POST['holding']` will be an array of the values, rather than just a single value.

Comment: That's not a PHP specific "hack", but more of a de-facto standard for submitting multiple values. Other frameworks behave exactly the same way.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I figured it out, thank you for all the help! This is what I used:

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($mysqli, "UPDATE w_o SET w_status = 'hold' WHERE id = ?");

        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $id);
        foreach ($_POST['holding'] as $id) 
        {
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        }
```

I think I tried this earlier, but didn't set `holding` as an array. Thank you again for all the help!!!

Answer (score -2):

```
$sql = "UPDATE w_o SET w_status = 'hold' WHERE id in (".array_map("intval",implode(',',$_POST['holding'][$i])).")";
```

so you can update all of them with single sql

Comment: and doesn't work anyways, since PHP will only accept a single value for a field name unless it's got `[]` at the end.

Comment: While well-intentioned, `intval` is not a substitute for proper escaping as it's not a general-purpose solution.

Comment: yeah sorry for the ,$_POST['holding'][$i]. You should gather the ids with a loop before the sql. and use it instead of $_POST['holding'][$i]

Comment: OK, I tried changing the name of `holding` to an array `holding[$i]` and it decided to change all the fields to hold. I thought that using `isset()` would resolve that?